# Simplify a expression with nested radical signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify :

$\sqrt{10+6 \sqrt{2}+5 \sqrt{3}+4 \sqrt{6}}$

I have tried completing square but failed, Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could write $a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6=\sqrt{10+6\sqrt2+5\sqrt3+4\sqrt6}$, square both sides, set like coefficients equal, and try to solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you. This is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$10+6 \sqrt{2}+5 \sqrt{3}+4 \sqrt{6}=5(2+\sqrt3)+2\sqrt6(2+\sqrt3)=(2+\sqrt3)(5+2\sqrt6)$$

Now, $$5+2\sqrt6=3+2+2\cdot\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt3=(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^2$$

and $$2+\sqrt3=\frac{4+2\sqrt3}2=\frac{3+1+2\cdot\sqrt3\cdot1}2=\frac{(\sqrt3+1)^2}2$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Very nice work! Thank you, I see.

Comment: @maplematica, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$10+6\sqrt2+5\sqrt3+4\sqrt6=2(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2+6\sqrt2+5\sqrt3\;\ldots$$

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit?